# PHP mailform send to email?

Tags: php, forms, email

I have used a PHP script I got from my teacher on this page;
But since I'm very inexperienced in PHP I can't figure it out.
I still need to set the address the email gets send to, but I don't know where to do that.
I thought I needed to fill that in at 'mail' but it now says the message can't be send.
So is this a problem with my host/site/something or am I still doing anything wrong with the coding?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD><TITLE>www.lucsenden.nl - Voor al uw videoproducties.</TITLE>

<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>

<META name=robots content=index,follow>

<META name=keywords content=" ">

<META name=description content=" ">

<META content=0 http-equiv=Expires><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style.css" media=screen>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pngfix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
DD_belatedPNG.fix('img,#logo');
</script> 
<![endif]-->

<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css/ie.css" media=screen>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<DIV class=top-bar-wrap>&nbsp;</DIV>

<DIV class=main-bg>

<DIV id=sub-page class=main-wrap>

<DIV id=header class=mod-con>

<H1 id=logo><A href="/#"><IMG alt="" src="/image/luc.png"></A></H1>

<UL id=main-menu>

<LI><A href="/index.html"><STRONG>Home</STRONG></A><A class=cur href="/about.html"><STRONG>Over mij</STRONG></A> </LI>

<LI><A href="/diensten.html"><STRONG>Diensten</STRONG></A> </LI>

<LI><A href="/portfolio.html"><STRONG>Portfolio</STRONG></A> </LI>

<LI><A href="/referenties.html"><STRONG>Referenties</STRONG></A> </LI>

<LI><A href="/contact.html"><STRONG>Contact</STRONG></A> </LI></UL></DIV>

<DIV id=main class=mod-con>

<DIV class="container clearfix">

<DIV style="WIDTH: 861px;HEIGHT: 1006px" id=about-page class=main-con>

<DIV class=title-nav>

<H2>Contact</H2></DIV>

<DIV class=content>

<P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et risus non arcu porttitor feugi at in at neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin pretium neque at turpis fermentum de aliquet. Ut risus nisi, scelerisque in convallis et, volutpat malesuada elit. Ut nulla libero, condi entum eget scelerisque eget, blandit sit amet metus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla luctus temus augue dictum cursus. Curabitur non risus dui. In sit amet tellus in lacus fringilla condimentuma t sit amet libero. Fusce purus ligula, hendrerit ut vulputate eget, vestibulum non diam. Vestib ulum facilisis, leo id volutpat vestibulum, eros ligula ornare urna, pellentesque laoreet magna purus ac metus. Nulla facilisi.</P>
<?php

echo '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $subject = $_POST['naam'].' stuurde een mail via PHP!';
    $email = $_POST[''];
    $bericht = wordwrap($_POST['bericht'], 70);

    $versturen_gelukt = mail($email, $subject, $bericht);

    if($versturen_gelukt) {
        echo '      <p>De email is verstuurd! <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">Nog een mail sturen</a>.</p>'."\r\n";
    } else {
        echo '      <p>Er is iets mis gegaan, <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">probeer het opnieuw</a>.</p>'."\r\n";
    }

} else {

    echo '
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST" type="text/plain">

        <label for="name">Naam</label>
            <input type="naam" name="naam" id="naam" />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />

        <label for="bericht">Bericht</label>
            <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht"></textarea>

        <label for="submit"></label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Stuur bericht!" />

    </form>
    ';
}

echo ' ';

?>
</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>

<DIV class=siteintro-wrap>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV class=footer-wrap>
    <DIV id=footer class=mod-con>
    <DIV class=copyright>&#169 2012 Copyright  All Rights Reserved.
    </DIV>
        <DIV class=hovergallery>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/lucsenden"><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/10p9g5i.png" /></a>
        <a href="http://youtube.com/luckske112"><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/34rwqdv.png" /></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/lucsenden"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/xfst8g.png" /></a>
        </DIV>
    </DIV></DIV></BODY></html>
    ';

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When somebody accesses a website, the webserver parses the PHP code and returns the output that it generates. Therefore, if we attempt to view the source of your site, all we see is the generated output - not the underlying PHP code. You will have to edit your question and try to add the source code again. Also, check the [manual on PHP's `mail()` function](http://php.net/mail).

Comment: No, we cannot find the PHP source of your page. Edit your question, paste the code in, select it and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar to mark it as code.

Comment: I have changed the code, sorry for that. I am now going to read the link Kristian gave me.

Comment: Does that code even run? As you can see in the syntax color highlighting, it's broken with inconsistently nested quotes. You also do not need to `echo` all HTML from PHP. Just close the PHP tag `?>`, write HTML outside PHP, then open `<?php` again when you need to write PHP code.

Comment: Okay, I changed the code. This is how it's supposed to be?
Also, I think it runs because I get that error message 'Er is iets mis gegaan,probeer het opnieuw.'

Answer (score 3):

You're writing

```
$email = $_POST['email@hotmail.com'];
```

This basically means that that the `$email` variable (the recipient) is set to whatever content the field named `email@hotmail.com` contains. This would be a very odd name for a field name, and luckily you don't have a field name like that.

Instead, you should write

```
$email = "email@hotmail.com";
```

*That* email address will be the recipient of your email.